# Database architecture in mongodb with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, mongodb

I am using MongoDB and Ruby on rails to Build a webservice. I have around 10GB of data. Collections(similar to Tables in RDBMS)in the data are divided by states in a country and the fields in the collection differ slightly from collection to collection. I have 60 collections. I wont have problems if I combine 2-3 collection with different fields as I am using a nosql database.

My problem
If have dont combine my collections then I would have 60 models in my rails application. If I combine them all then I would have a very large collection and performance would reduce. What would be the optimum choice as my server resources are limited.I will query my database based on 3-4 different parameters. For example I may only search for a particular area or may be for a particular license type a person owns or both some times.

Comment: Did you try one large collection? with proper indexes should work just fine.

Comment: I didnt try anything yet. I wanna make sure I start with the right thing and your suggegstion seems promising. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergio said, one large collection with indexes on the 3-4 fields you query on will probably work best.

However, you don't have to have 60 models, just use dynamic fields. This is one of the main benefits of using MongoDB. You can read about it in mongoid [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/dynamic.html). Basically, just define the fields that are common to all of the documents in the collection and then set and get the dynamic fields as needed.

The one gotcha here is that the method (".", dot) attribute accesor doesn't work until that attribute is set. So you can't say model.attribute until you have set one via model[:attribute] = "blah" or model.attribute = "blah".